# spark-sql is not supporting partition drop

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the following query to drop hive table partition through `spark-sql`:

```
Alter table TABLE_NAME drop if exists partition (PARTITION_STRING)
```

I am getting the error below:

> AnalysisException: mismatched input 'DROP' expecting KW_EXCHANGE near **TABLE_NAME** in alter exchange partition;

Comment: alter table tbl drop if exists partition(date='2018-01-01') worked for me on spark sql. Few things to note: 1. Only '=' works in spark sql. 2. Format to specify partition string is : (partition_filed='value').

Comment: @kalpesh  what if the  value keeps getting changed can we pass a variable here in place of "value"   : (partition_filed='value')?

Comment: @Vin Yes, you can do that in spark-sql. Eg.
set date = 20161201;
Alter table test_schema.test_table drop partition (date='${date}');

Comment: @kalpesh but that is something you do in scala I was working in pyspark and second  question how about <> condition do you happen to know if someone got to work around it ?

Comment: @Vin I had searched lot for <>, but this doesn't seem to work anyway. I think syntax explains itself, its 'drop partition' not 'drop partitions'.